# Filling a multicolumn ListBox from another UserForm ListBox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Currently I have formatted a UserForm (that can be seen in the attached image below) that has the user select certain checkbox criteria, followed by adding and removing countries back and forth from 2 list boxes (row source = 'All Countries Validation'!$A$4:$A$61 for ListBox1).

After selecting their criteria, they click a button ("Extract Data")  and it highlights all fields in the "Selected Countries" listbox (image 2 = after button has been clicked).

If I could just get some assistance/guidance on after clicking the button, the countries listed in ListBox 2 could appear in a first column in ListBox3, that would be amazing. The ultimate goal is for the user to select criteria in the UserForm, and information about countries the user selected will be returned in ListBox3. If it's easier to return this information in a Message Box that works too.

Code below returns selected countries in a msgbox

```
Dim x As Integer
For x = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
If ListBox2.Selected(x) = False Then
    ListBox2.Selected(x) = True
End If
Next
Dim Range1 As Range

Msg = ""
For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox2.Selected(i) Then _
        Msg = Msg & ListBox2.List(i) & vbCrLf
Next i
MsgBox "You selected: " & vbCrLf & Msg
Unload Me
```

[image: UserForm]

[image: UserForm After Clicked]

Code Below when Contract Revenue, Actual, Davey is checked:

```
    If CheckBox1.Value = True And CheckBox2.Value = False And CheckBox3.Value = False Then
        If CheckBox4.Value = True And CheckBox5.Value = False Then
            If CheckBox6.Value = True And CheckBox7.Value = False Then
```

Comment: TL;DR....Take selected column information from one UserList, and find row information about selected items in an excel sheet to then paste into a second UserList

Comment: What have you tried? Given what you have done so far, it seems like that shouldn't be too hard of a task.

Comment: So I added the code that I have for the condition Contract Revenue, Actual, Davey is checked. In total there are 63 possible conditions that I have written. I'm curious to know how to pull column data from an excel sheet and insert it into a 3rd list box/msgbox